# How to scale multiple UV face in proportion?

Tags: uv

I have a mesh unwrapped which I need to ensure that each face of same size occupy the exactly the same texture space (pixel-perfect).

This holds true when I simply use the basic unwrap option.  However, when I select the concerned faces in the UV/Image editor tab and scale them at once, the resulting faces loses proportion.

I think the problem is that I can only scale the faces based on one pivot point, hence the faces are scaled differently depending on their respective distance from the choice of pivot centre.

So, I am wondering if there is any option available so that each face is scaled using their own centre as the pivot point? Otherwise, does anyone know how I can achieve what I want?

Many thanks!

Comment: The problem is that by scaling you are sacling also their own location coordinates, right? You have a group of faces that you would like to have theur uvface scaled in position while the other stay still. This will create a non-uniform margin in the uvmap, is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: inevitably yes, the UV coordinates also get scaled at the moment when scaling them normally.  Ideally however, while I want each of the faces' area in the UV space be scaled uniformly, I would prefer them to stay attached.